# faster way to iterate through and compare two lists of classes

Tags: c#

i need to iterate through and compare 2 lists of classes and compare the 2 and output the matching records.  this is taking hours and i cant figure out a way to speed up the process. the lists are roughly 600k records a piece. here is my code for the class and code for iterating through and comparing.

```
class Person
{
    string NPI;
    string address;
    string zip5;
    string lname;
    string lsk;
    string state;
    string fname;
    string zipfull;
    string seqNo;

    public Person(string npi, string Address, string Zip5, string Lname, string LSK, string st, string Fname, string zipFull, string seqno)
    {
        this.NPI = npi;
        this.address = Address;
        this.zip5 = Zip5;
        this.lname = Lname;
        this.lsk = LSK;
        this.state = st;
        this.fname = Fname;
        this.zipfull = zipFull;
        this.seqNo = seqno;
    }

    public string getNPI()
    {
        return NPI;
    }

    public string getzip5()
    {
        return zip5;
    }

    public string getaddress()
    {
        return address;
    }
    public string Full()
    {
        string full = NPI + "," + address + "," + zip5 + "," + lname + "," + lsk + "," + state + "," + fname + "," + zipfull + "," + seqNo;
        return full;
    }
}
```

here is the code for iterating through. the fuzz.ratio is a fuzzy matching nuget package i downloaded and i know that isnt the problem as i have done speed tests with it and it is very fast

```
string inputfile = @"C:\Input_File_150k.csv";
string blacklist = @"C:\Blacklist1.csv";
List<Person> input = Readcsv(inputfile);
List<Person> BL = Readcsv(blacklist);

string outputtest = @"C:\outputtest.csv";
StringBuilder csvcontent = new StringBuilder();

int lengthinput = input.Count();
for(int i = 0; i <lengthinput; i++)
{
    int lengthbl = BL.Count();
    for(int x = 0; x < lengthbl; x++)
    {
        if(input[i].getzip5() == BL[x].getzip5())
        {
            if(input[i].getNPI() == BL[x].getNPI())
            {
                if(Fuzz.Ratio(input[i].getaddress(),BL[x].getaddress()) > 90)
                {
                    csvcontent.AppendLine(input[i].Full());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

File.AppendAllText(outputtest, csvcontent.ToString());
```

Comment: Only way I can think of off the top of my head is to parallelize the search. You might also be able to reduce your [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), as your algorithm right now is of `O(n^2)` time complexity

Comment: You could turn one of them into a dictionary with the zip and NPI as the key then use that as a lookup while looping over the other one. That will change the complexity from O(n*m) to O(n+m) where n and m are the lengths of each list.

Comment: Also you really should change from using get methods to readonly properties `public string NPI { get; }`

Comment: If the code you have works, and you'd like a review of all aspects of the code, and your question meets their criteria, you may be able to ask this question on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a dictionary from one list to use as a lookup while iterating the other.  That will change the complexity from polynomial to linear.

```
string inputfile = @"C:\Input_File_150k.csv";
string blacklist = @"C:\Blacklist1.csv";
List<Person> input = Readcsv(inputfile);
var blAddresses = Readcsv(blacklist).ToDictionary(
    x => (Zip : x.getzip5(), NPI : x.getNPI()),
    x => x.getaddress());

string outputtest = @"C:\outputtest.csv";
StringBuilder csvcontent = new StringBuilder();

int lengthinput = input.Count();
for(int i = 0; i <lengthinput; i++)
{
    var zip = input[i].getzip5();
    var npi = input[i].getNPI();

    if(blAddresses.TryGetValue((zip,npi), out var blAddress)
    {
        if(Fuzz.Ratio(input[i].getaddress(),blAddress) > 90)
        {
            csvcontent.AppendLine(input[i].Full());            
        }
    }
}

File.AppendAllText(outputtest, csvcontent.ToString());
```

Specifically I've created a dictionary that keys on the Zip and NPI and gets the Address which is all that's needed.  I'm using some C# 7 stuff like the value tuples, but that can be changed to reference tuples, anonymous class, or a custom class if needed.

**Edit**

Here's a change to make this work just as your current code does assuming that you have duplicate Zip/NPI values

```
string inputfile = @"C:\Input_File_150k.csv";
string blacklist = @"C:\Blacklist1.csv";
List<Person> input = Readcsv(inputfile);
var blAddresses = Readcsv(blacklist)
    .GroupBy(x => (Zip : x.getzip5(), NPI : x.getNPI()))
    .ToDictionary(
        grp => grp.Key, 
        grp => grp.Select(y => y.getAddress()).ToList());

string outputtest = @"C:\outputtest.csv";
StringBuilder csvcontent = new StringBuilder();

int lengthinput = input.Count();
for(int i = 0; i <lengthinput; i++)
{
    var zip = input[i].getzip5();
    var npi = input[i].getNPI();

    if(blAddresses.TryGetValue((zip,npi), out var blAddressList)
    {
        foreach(var blAddress in blAddressList)
        {
            if(Fuzz.Ratio(input[i].getaddress(),blAddress) > 90)
            {
                csvcontent.AppendLine(input[i].Full());       
            }     
        }
    }
}

File.AppendAllText(outputtest, csvcontent.ToString());
```

Alternatively if you just need to filter out anything in the black list where the NPI is blank to have unique keys you can do this instead

```
var blAddresses = Readcsv(blacklist)
    .Whree(x => x.getNPI().Length > 0) 
    .ToDictionary(
        x => (Zip : x.getzip5(), NPI : x.getNPI()),
        x => x.getaddress());
```

Comment: so i just tried this the problem is that some NPIs are blank so it is telling me that a key was already created when the zip and blank blank npi are the same. is there a way i could have it ignore blank NPIs

Comment: @bigs89 Do you want to completely ignore those or do you still need to match on blank NPI's, specifically can `inputfile` have a blank NPI that you want to match with a blank NPI in the black list?

Comment: @bigs89 I've updated my answer with an alternative that will work the way your current code does given that there can be duplicate zip/npi values, or you can alternatively filter out the blank NPIs, but it really depends on the exact data you expect to get and how you want to handle it.

Comment: awesome thank you this worked and will speed up my process immensely.  one more question  if im using this and want to fuzzy match more than one field other than address would i just do x=>x.getaddress(), p => p.getlnam()

Comment: @bigs89 You could just do `x => x` to get the entire object, or `x => (Address: x.getaddress(), Inam:x.getInam())` with naming.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through each list once to put all the values in a hash map. For instance, you can use the zip code as the key, and the value is an array of people who match that zip code.

Then you can iterate through the hashmap one record at a time, and only have to compare the people inside each hashmap bucket with eachother.

Unless all your people are in the same zip code (if so, hopefully one of your keys would work for this), this should be faster than N^2 comparison. Should be closer to O(N) depending on how many people are in each bucket.

Comment: Actually they need to hash the zip and NPI.

Comment: Anything would be faster than without hashmap at N^2 but yes, hash map buckets by multiple values would be better.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to above comments ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/60886352/5334191 and using Dictionaries), 
in your loops

```
int lengthinput = input.Count();
    **int lengthbl = BL.Count();** //move out of the loops

    for(int i = 0; i <lengthinput; i++)
    {
        **var inputi = input[i];**  //move out of the inner loop
        for(int x = 0; x < lengthbl; x++)
        {
            **var blx =  BL[x];**
            if(inputi.getzip5() == blx.getzip5())
            {
                if(inputi.getNPI() == blx.getNPI())
                {
                    if(Fuzz.Ratio(inputi.getaddress(),blx.getaddress()) > 90)
                    {
                        csvcontent.AppendLine(inputi.Full());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `Count` extension method when run on a `List` will just get the `Count` property value and not actually iterate the collection to get the count if that's what you're thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I would definity implement the IEqualityComparer interface.

That allows for much cleaner code and to also benefit from some of the Linq extension methods available on collections.

Those also support things like parallelism.

https://marcofranssen.nl/delegate-your-equality-comparisons/

Answer (score -1):

I think this part of code may be slow

> string full = NPI + "," + address + "," + zip5 + "," + lname + "," + lsk + "," + state + "," + fname + "," + zipfull + "," + seqNo;

What if you perform `csvcontent.Append` on those properties and `,` "manually" instead of using `Full()`? ps: it would require to add an possibility to read it from the outside, so public get / private set